# Can a string be replaced using shorthand directives in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If I want to replace a string in a URL with `htaccess`, I can do it longhand like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)shop/css(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1css%2 [L]
```

So if I wanted to write that in shorthand, I thought that I needed to do this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)shop/css(.*)$ %1css%2 [NC,L]
```

But that doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: In your last rule, you are using wrong backrefrences. %n should be $n

Comment: It works for the longhand version. But I gave it a try and changing the shorthand version to use $ instead of % didn't change anything.

Comment: What do you mean by doesnt work? What error are you getting ?

Comment: I mean that the shorthand (using $ or %) doesn't redirect any file that has the string `shop/css`. The longhand version does correctly redirect the urls with the `shop/css` string. I'm not getting an error with the shorthand, I'm getting no result. That's what I mean by it doesn't work.